# Issues with classpath running Jetty via Maven

Tags: maven, jetty

I'm using Maven to manage my build.  For developer testing I use Jetty which I launch using the jetty:run goal in the Jetty Maven plugin. I should also note that I have war:exploded running in an earlier phase which builds the directory that Jetty runs against.

The problem I'm having is that the war:exploded task puts the build dependencies into WEB-INF/lib (as it should) and furthermore, Maven appears to be feeding Jetty the build classpath via the system classloader.  This leads to every jar getting loaded twice which *should* be OK except that, sadly, the Datanucleus library throw an exception the second time it gets loaded onto the classpath.

The only solution I can think of at the moment is to create two profiles, a build profile and a developer test profile.  The developer test profile would exclude all the dependencies and jetty:run would run in the developer test profile.  This seems like a lot of configuration for something I think would be simple.

Does anyone know if there is a way to prevent Maven from loading the build classpath into Jetty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
<version>6.1.26</version>
<configuration>
    <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>
```

...

The option "useTestClasspath" should have the effect you are looking for.